# Switch between Hosted and Scaleset agents in Azure Devops during runtime

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have scaleset agents configured and working fine. But i would also like to take advantage of Microsoft Hosted agents whenever possible. So i added a parameter to the pipeline to choose which agent pool to use for that particular pipeline run.

[image]

I manged to set the pool/image variables based on the chosen parameter but unable to make a container job use the selected pool due to a difference in syntax as shown below.

[image]

Is there a way to modify the schema of yaml template based on the user selected parameter.
I think we need to not display `vmImage` property conditionally. I tried below snippet but it doesn't work. `vmImage` property is always missing.

```
  pool:
    ${{ if ne(parameters.pool, 'Azure Pipelines') }}:
      name: ${{ parameters.pool }}
    ${{ if eq(parameters.pool, 'Azure Pipelines') }}:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

UPDATED:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: pool
  displayName: Agent Pool
  type: string
  default: Scalesets
  values:
  - Scalesets
  - Hosted


    jobs:
    - deployment: '${{ parameters.jobName }}'
      displayName: ${{ coalesce(parameters.jobDisplayName, 'Deploy Infrastructure') }}
      ${{ if parameters.dependsOn }}:
        dependsOn: '${{ parameters.dependsOn }}'
      ${{ if parameters.condition }}:
        condition: '${{ parameters.condition }}'
      pool:
        name: ${{ parameters.pool }}
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' 
      container:
         image: '${{ parameters.image }}'
         endpoint: 'Container Registry - Prd'
      environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    
      variables:   
        - name: 'Release-Tag'
          value: '${{ parameters.release }}'
        - name: 'Layer'
          value: '${{ parameters.environmentLayer }}'
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:
           steps:
             - script: |
                echo $(Release-Tag) $(Layer)
               displayName: 'Show release condidate'
```

Comment: Can you show your example with container job?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej updated my question with more yaml.

Comment: Can you add also you runtime parameters declaration?

Comment: updated. It's about conditionally showing/hiding a property in yaml. You can reproduce it with simple hard coded value in condition. I think it's not specific to container jobs as well. It could be reproducible in any simple yaml template.

Comment: @Venky I am trying to change my answer to the form of options. I will update my answer later if I have any progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data type of your parameters as object. The value of object type can be any YAML structure. Please find more details about data types of parameters in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#parameters).
Here is my sample:

```
parameters:
  - name: pool
    type: object
    default:
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: build
  pool: ${{ parameters.pool }}
  steps:
  - script: echo Hello, world!
```

You can also choose the job to run based on the value of your parameters:

```
trigger: none
parameters:
  - name: type
    type: string
    values: 
    - Scalesets
    - Hosted

jobs:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.type, 'Scalesets') }}:
  - job: Scalesets
    pool: Default
    steps:
    - script: echo Scalesets
- ${{ if eq(parameters.type, 'Hosted') }}:
  - job: Hosted
    pool: 
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hosted
```

Comment: Thanks. In the above snippet how do i show options for user to select in AZDO UI?. I want to show options `Hosted` and  `Scalesets` and based on the selection of option i need to pick a template expression to insert into job.

Comment: @Venky How about the issue? Can the second way solve your problem?  Please let me know the latest information about this issue.